# How to identify token transfers looking at a transaction?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, bsc

Let's take this transaction as an example.

If I use [web3js](/questions/tagged/web3js) `getTransaction` method and decode the payload, it will give me information such as:

```js
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0xB54eB0cc6457e9d74e20672D8961faD3CDE4511c',
  gas: 474186,
  gasPrice: '5000000000',
  hash: '0xcf95271d63836f17c0c3a7beda7df2ea7029ce9161dc6808da86f5f9ce740830',
  input: {
    method: 'swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens',
    names: [ 'amountOutMin', 'path', 'to', 'deadline' ]
    types: [ 'uint256', 'address[]', 'address', 'uint256' ],
    inputs: [
      '152321810000000000',
      [
        'bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c',
        'd7b729ef857aa773f47d37088a1181bb3fbf0099'
      ],
      'b54eb0cc6457e9d74e20672d8961fad3cde4511c',
      '16211723261200'
    ],
  },
  nonce: 9,
  to: '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E',
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: '5000000000000000',
  v: '0x94',
  r: '0x4bac2f3fd76aecc8a6df23add9dabdb897aed3a2114021f30164867ef6039feb',
  s: '0x6de74caad4ef39d5cd71cd79058675308f725f36184cdc0ce82fc259096c31a9'
}
```

This describes inputs of the transaction. However, if we look again at the [BSCScan transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcf95271d63836f17c0c3a7beda7df2ea7029ce9161dc6808da86f5f9ce740830), it also includes information about what tokens were transferred:

```
From PancakeSwap: Router v2
To 0xd423fde466315d45fb0da457df28d5eeb92be580
For 0.005 ($2.97) Wrapped BNB (WBNB)

From 0xd423fde466315d45fb0da457df28d5eeb92be580
To 0xb54eb0cc6457e9d74e20672d8961fad3cde4511c
For 0.154823285118196657 ($2.94) Bogged Finan... (BOG)
```

How is this information determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ERC-20 specification describes some events that a token contract must emit when doing certain actions, like transferring tokens. If you look at [the logs for the transaction you linked](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcf95271d63836f17c0c3a7beda7df2ea7029ce9161dc6808da86f5f9ce740830#eventlog) for example, you can see a few `Transfer` events in there, including the address they were sent from and to, and the number of tokens that were transferred.

`web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` includes the logs, which you can decode to check the events emitted by a transaction.

Comment: I somehow overlooked that transactions themselves have logs. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've asked a follow up question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99071/how-do-i-determine-the-abi-to-use-for-web3-eth-abi-decodelog